# Issue in starting Django server

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I followed the instructions given on Django docs and did the following:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
cd mysite
python3 manage.py runserver
```

I get the following error :

```
 File "/home/dox/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'
```

My Django version is 3.0.4

Comment: I think the issue might me related with version of Django 3 and its compatibility with python 3.6 , try installing lower  Django version like 2.2, with command `pip install django==2.2` , first make sure you remove current version of django

Comment: You can try different ports by `manage.py  runserver your_port`. For example: `manage.py runserver 8002`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## you missed period in the end of project name

do in this manner,

```
django-admin startproject mysite .
```

note: no need to use cd mysite command just run server after this.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves the problem for v3.0.4! Switching the version to 2.2 also solves the issue without the period at the end.

Comment: So, if you found it helpful can you please mark my answer as helpful by clicking on upper arrow just in left left of my answer. Also to click on tick ill be happy   :)